# How to handle internationalization of names in Hiberante and db schema

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, api, internationalization

I saw a few questions in stackoverflow, but they all refer to old answers (from 2004) and using hibernate xml mappings.

I am writing an API in Java, which will return products which are stored in the database based on an algorithm.

The API would also get a locale and decide to return the name in the locale language.

Product table:

```
product_id
name
price
```

How should I support internalization?
Should I add `name_en` `name_fr` etc columns?

Or should I create different tables?

How should I return the name in the required locale in Hibernate?

I am using annotations for O/R mapping

Comment: It depends on the number of the languages you need to support. Are there a few and fixed languages? (for example English, French and German?). If that's the case I recommend using multiple fields, otherwise you shall use another table. By the way you can use a `Map<String, String>` mapping in Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks @AmirPashazadeh but who would you create a multiple table? and retrieve only the desired column per locale?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a column "lang" that contains prefix of language (ex. en, fr, ro, etc.) and a column "name" that contains the name in all languages separated by a separator like "," and parse the string.

Comment: How would you retrieve by it only the name in the desired language with Hibernate?

Comment: You will have to get the whole string that contains all the names in all languages (separated by ",") and then select only the n-th substring of that string.

Comment: For example, if language is English, select the first substring (until the first ","), if the language is French, select the second substring (between the first and the second ",").

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the `name` column, and create a one-to-many relationship with a separate table named `localized_name`:

```
create table localized_name (
    product_key int not null,
    locale nvarchar(32) not null,
    name nvarchar(255) not null
)
```

My experience is with JPA, not Hibernate, but I'm guessing the code looks similar in both:

```
public class Product {
    private Collection<LocalizedName> names;
}
```

In JPA I would add a `@Size(min = 1)` annotation to the field to ensure it contains at least one element when it is persisted.

Comment: How would I retrieve only one name per locale on hibernate criteria/ hql?

Comment: `select p.names.name from Product p where p.names.locale = :locale`